# AOSP RIL access of Nexus-S

Tags: android, android-source, nexus-s, ril

My Objective :

My objective is to  access RIL layer of AOSP and try to access radio layer to know about Primary and Secondary PDP bearer creation by using "AT" command. Also i want to access ISIM authentication parameters of SIM card to handle AKA-v1 algo. I have  Nexus-S and Galaxy S3 LTE phone but i am doing experiment on Nexus-S as AOSP is available. I am doing developing VoLTE application and embedding my application in AOSP/Custom ROM to access RIL/SIM access.

What I did :

I flashed AOSP on my Nexus phone and trying to use - OEM_HOOK_RAW to send some AT command to radio layer. I am able to send my "AT" command to RILC but RILC is treating it as error. Following is the error messages -

```
01-07 17:34:24.921 D/RILJ    (  541): [0096]> OEM_HOOK_STRINGS
01-07 17:34:24.924 V/RILJ    (  541): writing packet: 24 bytes
01-07 17:34:24.924 D/RILC    (   86): (processCommandBuffer, 379):: Command Request Code = 60
,, pStrings = AT24 D/RILC    (   86): (dispatchStrings, 470):: printBuf = (AT
)1-07 17:34:24.924 D/RILC    (   86): [0096]> OEM_HOOK_STRINGS (AT
01-07 17:34:24.924 D/RILC    (   86): (dispatchStrings, 478):: Command Request number = 60, Token = 96
01-07 17:34:24.924 D/RILC    (   86): [0096]< OEM_HOOK_STRINGS fails by E_REQUEST_NOT_SUPPORTED
```

I picked the Samsung RIL library from  - /vendor/lib/libsec-ril.so and verified "requestOEMHookRaw" is available in Samsung RIL.

I am very much sure that I am doing some thing wrong. I am very thankful if some body send any reference document/post to help me.

Also I have Samsung Galaxy S3 LTE device based on Qualcom chipset and Qualcom exposed its GOBI based API to run "AT" command. Is it possible to use GOBI based API to access RIL etc. Has anybody worked on it?